# 2.8 Light Bleeding in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am modeling a quick interior scene in Eevee but I cannot seem to get past the light that appears to be bleeding through the small crevices of the cube and the randomly lit regions. I solidified it and selected ambient occlusion in an attempt to resolve this as some suggested, but it's just not working. What am I doing wrong here? Will you please help me resolve this?

[image]

Here is the blender file:
[quick_interior.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52305)

Answer (score 1):

EEVEE is not good at calculating shadow light path, since it's not ray tracing.

There is a **contact shadow** option in your light source setting:

[image]

It uses ray tracing to **"fix"** those bleeding area:

[image]

In game practice, light will not likely put outside the wall, and should use some light stop method to make it stay in specified area. Might use Cycles for those great lighting result.

Comment: Okay, I will use Cycles for better lighting results. Eevee is not pulling through with the type of lighting I'm trying to achieve in my scene. The contact shadow tip certainly helped resolve this problem, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your light's Shadow settings, adjust the Exponent value to be higher.

Comment: This tip worked as well. Thank you!